# Change compile still error in build-gradle

Tags: android, android-studio

When I press "rebuild project" I get this error. I have try everything, search on the internet, but nothing works. I really wants to test my app to see if the app is working.

```
Executing tasks: [:app:generateDebugSources, :libtimesquare:generateDebugSources]

Configuration on demand is an incubating feature.
WARNING: Configuration 'compile' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'implementation' and 'api'.
It will be removed at the end of 2018. For more information see: http://d.android.com/r/tools/update-dependency-configurations.html
registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedResFolders(FileCollection)
registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedResFolders(FileCollection)
:app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:libtimesquare:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:libtimesquare:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:libtimesquare:checkDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
:libtimesquare:processDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
:app:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:libtimesquare:compileDebugAidl UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugAidl UP-TO-DATE
:libtimesquare:packageDebugRenderscript NO-SOURCE
:app:compileDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:app:checkDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareLintJar UP-TO-DATE
:app:mainApkListPersistenceDebug UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugGoogleServices
Parsing json file: /home/app/google-services.json
:libtimesquare:compileDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:libtimesquare:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
:libtimesquare:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:libtimesquare:packageDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:createDebugCompatibleScreenManifests UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
:app:splitsDiscoveryTaskDebug UP-TO-DATE
:libtimesquare:platformAttrExtractor UP-TO-DATE
:libtimesquare:generateDebugRFile UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugSources UP-TO-DATE
:libtimesquare:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:libtimesquare:prepareLintJar UP-TO-DATE
:libtimesquare:generateDebugSources UP-TO-DATE

BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 1s
24 actionable tasks: 1 executed, 23 up-to-date
```

Comment: This question needs an [mcve] to be on topic. Do readers need to see Java code? This does not look like an error, since the build is successful. Are you not getting an executable being compiled?

Comment: That's just a warning tho. Go to `build.gradle`, change dependencies which starts by `compile` to `implementation` that's it.

Answer (score 0):

"BUILD SUCCESSFUL"

The warning to replace `compile` with `implementation` is just a warning, not an error. If you're using `implementation` for your Gradle dependencies, then one of them is using `compile`, and you need to wait for the authors to update them.

There's nothing preventing you from testing your app.

Comment: when i run app in the android -studio, i get build failed..it  doesent work :(